# FifoQueue does not name a type

Tags: omnet++, inet

im new to OMNET++/INET and im trying to use the FifoQueue from the INET library. I included the header files but i can't use the class itself and says that FifoQueue does not name a type. I don't know what am i doing wrong.

```
    #ifndef SERVER_H_
#define SERVER_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
#include "inet/common/queue/FifoQueue.h"

using namespace omnetpp;
using namespace std;

class Server : public cSimpleModule
{
    private:
        cMessage *refillCapacity;
        cMessage *checkQueue;

        double checkTimer = 0.001;
        double refillTimer = 1.0;
        FifoQueue *Searchqueue;//    IPassiveQueue a;

    protected:
        virtual void initialize() override;
        virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(Server);

#endif /* SERVER_H_ */
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the line

```
Define_Module(Server);
```

from the header file. This line is required but in source file.

`FifoQueue` is the simple module. So one can use it by placing it in own module defined in NED. An example of using it may be found in INET: `src\inet\networklayer\diffserv\AFxyQueue.ned`

Comment: Plus `using namespace inet;` is also missing. The `FifoQueue` is in the `inet` namespace.

Comment: Ohh, and it's name is `inet::FIFOQueue`, not `FifoQueue`